# PHP: Last n characters to a specified character in a string?

Tags: php, string, substr

I want to get the last **n** characters from a string, after the last "-" character. Like:

```
$string = "something-123";
$substring = 123;
$string2 = "something-253672-something-21";
$substring2 = 21;
```

These characters can only be numbers.
How can I do this with PHP?
(sorry for bad english)

Comment: Using a combination of [strrpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) to locate the lasyt hyphen (`-`) in the string, and then [substr()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could explode the string and parse the last element of the resulting array:

```
$splitted = explode("-", $string);
$numbers = end($splitted);

if (is_numeric($numbers)) {
    echo "Yay!";
} else {
    echo "Nay!";
}
```

Comment: @prigero While this answer works, there are more succinct answers provided that should be considered.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this function to solve ur problem.

```
 return is_numeric(array_pop(explode('-', $string)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Should do it in one line...

```
 substr($string, strrpos($string, '-') + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

And there is always a regex for it:

```
preg_match('/.*-([0-9]+)$/',$yourstring,$match);
echo $match[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code will work according to your query:

```
$mystring ="something-253672-something-21";
// Get position of last '-' character.
$pos = strrpos($mystring, "-");
// Get number after '-' character.
$last_number = substr($mystring,$pos+1);
echo $last_number;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following one-liner:

```
$substring = (int)end((explode("-", $string)));
```

it'll be always numeric (`0` if invalid number).